New Service to Service Protocol Presented for Public Scrutiny (Time-based Token Signing), Is it Safe?
I came up with the following protocol to provide a life-time for JWT tokens while differentiating services to communicate securely with web services (service-to-service) using symmetric key signing protocol rather than one based on prime integer factorization (RSA, EC etc.) on the signing end.  Below is an explanation of how it works.

S1 is Service N
WS is Web Service
HS512 is just a default implementation as the hash function is somewhat irrelevant here.  RS is similar to what would be a salt but really it's another key which makes K1 an identifying credential.
This buys a life-time for tokens during validation on the WS (Web Service) end while not revealing the secret in case of brute-force attacks.  Once a good hashing function is chosen a Quantum Computer will not have much of an advantage over a classical one to reverse the process to either get a hold of RS or K1 which are the actual keys.
Can anybody see a glaring issue with this protocol?

RS should not be max size limited
Add SK as the service key (not max size limited)
Change K1 to = HMAC(SK, C)
Asuming SHA-512 is chosen:
While the above changes would add negatively to performance and K1 is more of an identifier than a key why allow it to be cracked after 2^512 + 2^1024 iterations?  While the numbers seem pretty high today, some organizations can indeed host zetta-bytes of storage.  While that's not enough for a 2^512 hash-table it may be so in the future.  At that point HMAC portions will be the only limiting factors to get to the initial values by brute-force.  In such cases larger hash function outputs will be needed.
Clarification for the link:  Seagate blog post is only to demonstrate the growing data needs like that of a smart city.  The article mentions 150mm hard-drive of 10TB storage, whereas we know that there exists 50mm flash drives (Intel Micron 3D NAND) that can store 10TBs today that you don't have to line up end to end as if it was made of DNA.

I don't think K1 needs to be hashed but I can see why you may want to do that just to bring it to size for the XOR.  It's important to rotate RS as back tracking it should take the following steps:
What 512bit key verifies the message?
2^512 to bruteforce at which point you get the key, but it's not useful because WS won't validate the next message.
So to get RS you know a 1024 bit message will yield H(K2) and H(K1).
Then you'd have to get RS from there.  It should take a while as K1 is not necessarily a useful secret.
By then the validity period should have expired but going further for K2 is how long you have to rotate RS.  One would have to get unimaginably lucky to get to make a valid token.

H(K2) is actually the hash of the hash from HMAC.  You would have to find what yielded HMAC(RS, C) where C can be guessed (ish) with RS unknown.

I did think about just using HMAC(K1 (+) RS || RS, C) but I think having the first two layers of 2^512 and 2^1024 buys more time for such a small amount of computation time as well as getting a minimum size for RS in case it's set too short.

While I understand that, simply using HMAC can secure K1 and RS don't you think?  Plus JWT tokens already have their expiration mechanisms.  What's your point in using HS512 for this?  If you have a back channel already, simply exchange a key and encrypt the entire token.  That's what JWE tokens are for in fact.
